# Query row where there are n rows in given timerange tr before that row

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there are way in postgres sql to find a row `r` where there are at least `n` entries in the time range `tr` before timestamp `t` of that row?

Sample data:

```
id,timestamp
1,2019-08-10
2,2019-08-11
3,2019-08-20
4,2019-08-21
5,2019-08-22
6,2019-08-30
```

Ideal query:

```
select * from table where row_count_before_row=2 and timerange=2 days;
```

Wanted result:

```
5,2019-08-22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions with `range` for this purpose:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (order by timestamp
                            range between '2 day' preceding and current row
                           ) - 1 as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9fd20cd360e2f50cef4643de6a26b611) is a db<>fiddle.

The `- 1` is because the current row is counted but you specified "before".  You can also do some trick like:

```
count(*) over (order by timestamp
               range between '2 day' preceding and '1 second' preceding
               )  as cnt
```